# Delete a ParseFile

Tags: android, parse-platform

I need to delete files that a user may have uploaded from my app is the user chooses to disconnect their account from my app but I dont see any way to do this

doing a quick google search I found this question

https://www.parse.com/questions/how-can-i-delete-a-file

but its over 2 years old and is a terrible solution IMO. Having to put your master key in the app that anyone can get at so you can delete a file with the REST API is far less secure than his explanation for not being able to delete from the SDK

is this really the only way to delete a file still?

Answer (score 1):

From the data browser you can remove all files that no longer have references pointing to them.

Go to "Settings", "General Settings", scroll down and you will see a "Clean up files" option.

Comment: yes but I have to manually do that which is not what I am looking for

Comment: sadly you do. There is no way to trigger this from code.